# Render partial aspx page (with codebehind) in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

is it possible to render an web-forms aspx page which has codebehind ?

atm I think that I'm going to do this using an iframe, but it would be much better without.

anybody knows if this is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have an aspx with codebehind, as long as its still a proper Mvc view. If it's a WebForms page with controls then things will probably not work. Also if you are using page events (PreRender etc) then it might also not work.

Composing the final output from a mix of Mvc views and WebForms pages is not supported. You will have to use things like iframes

The reason why views in Mvc usually don't have a codebehind is because this might encourage people to put application logic in them which is against the Mvc pattern

Comment: there are controls in that Page but the codebehind has only an empty Page_Load() method

Comment: so, the main requirement - keeping ASP.NET WebForm controls and corresponding rendering?

Comment: If the codebehind is empty then you can just delete the .cs file.

Comment: that's marvelous, all my asp.net server controls work in mvc as well  : )